# Down-scaling an UIImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiimageview, uiimage

I am having problems with resizing of my JPEG picture.

I would like it to be the size of the original picture, but instead it covers up the whole screen. I was trying `myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cube Tile.jpeg"]
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

This is what happened:

- My simulator screen gets covered with my image, but the height is slightly smaller.

I also tried adding this: `myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cube Tile.jpeg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]];`
This is what happened:

- My simulator screen gets covered with tiny versions of my image.

Is it possible doing this without too many lines of code?

Excuse me if I am a bit vaque.

- Note 1: The original picture is 24 x 24 pixels
- Note 2: I am a new developer, so I was just experimenting.

Thanks in advance, Marnix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the frame on the image view?  e.g.,

```
    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0.0;
    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,24,24)];
```

(and to make sure it's not trying to autosize based on a setting in the .xib)

```
    [myImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```

Comment: Is the Storyboard 'needed'? -M

Answer (score 0):

You could change the value of

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

to one of these Values:

```
 typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

See more at the official documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: Could you maybe explain to me how? -M

Comment: I found the fault: I had self.view = myImageView; it had to be [self.view addSubview: myImageView]; Thanks anyway.